# Vapor won't build on DigitalOcean via Docker

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, vapor, digital-ocean-apps

I have a Vapor app which I'd like to deploy on DigitalOcean.
The Vapor documentation suggests creating a droplet (and then setting up it manually including cloning from GitHub). But I'd like to have DC deploy my project automatically - so I created an app instead of droplet.
Unfortunately it won't build :(

Here's what I see in the logs (stripped):

```
[2022-07-28 21:17:13] => Initializing build
[2022-07-28 21:17:13] => Retrieving source code to /.app_platform_workspace
[2022-07-28 21:17:13] => Selecting branch "master"
[2022-07-28 21:17:13] => Checking out commit "86d8078be01b1bd38412c8657bb935cb0e8381ed"
[2022-07-28 21:17:14] => Got source_dir: /
[2022-07-28 21:17:14] => Using workspace root /.app_platform_workspace
[2022-07-28 21:17:14] => Got dockerfile_path: Dockerfile
[2022-07-28 21:17:14] 
[2022-07-28 21:17:14] => Building app using Dockerfile
[2022-07-28 21:17:15] => Using Dockerfile: /.app_platform_workspace/Dockerfile
[2022-07-28 21:17:15] => Using build context /.app_platform_workspace//
[2022-07-28 21:17:15] 
[2022-07-28 21:17:16] INFO[0000] Resolved base name swift:5.6-focal to build  
...
[2022-07-28 21:19:34] INFO[0139] Running: [/bin/sh -c swift package resolve]  
[2022-07-28 21:19:38] 'build': warning: failed storing manifest for 'build' in cache: disk I/O error
[2022-07-28 21:19:38] warning: failed loading cached manifest for 'build': disk I/O error
[2022-07-28 21:19:38] INFO[0143] Pushed <registry-uri-6> 
...
[2022-07-28 21:19:39] [1/1143] Fetching objects
[2022-07-28 21:19:40] Fetched https://github.com/vapor/leaf.git (1.40s)
...
[2022-07-28 21:20:02] warning: failed loading cached manifest for 'leaf': disk I/O error
...
[2022-07-28 21:21:38] 'leaf': warning: failed loading cached manifest for 'leaf': disk I/O error
...                             
[2022-07-28 21:23:08] INFO[0352] args: [-c swift build -c release --static-swift-stdlib] 
[2022-07-28 21:23:08] INFO[0352] Running: [/bin/sh -c swift build -c release --static-swift-stdlib] 
[2022-07-28 21:23:15] 'build': warning: failed loading cached manifest for 'build': disk I/O error
[2022-07-28 21:23:19] 'vapor': warning: failed loading cached manifest for 'vapor': disk I/O error
[2022-07-28 21:23:19] 'fluent-postgres-driver': warning: failed loading cached manifest for 'fluent-postgres-driver': disk I/O error
[2022-07-28 21:23:19] 'leaf': warning: failed loading cached manifest for 'leaf': disk I/O error
...
[2022-07-28 21:24:22] Building for production...
[2022-07-28 21:24:25] [1/875] Compiling _NumericsShims _NumericsShims.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:25] [2/875] Compiling CNIOWindows WSAStartup.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:25] [3/875] Compiling CNIOWindows shim.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:26] [4/875] Compiling CVaporBcrypt bcrypt.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:26] [5/875] Compiling CVaporURLParser urlparser.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:26] [6/875] Compiling CVaporBcrypt blf.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:26] [7/875] Compiling CNIOLinux liburing_shims.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimizationerror: invalid driver name: swift-driver[8/875] Compiling CNIOSHA1 c_nio_sha1.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [9/875] Compiling CNIOLinux shim.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [10/875] Compiling CNIOExtrasZlib empty.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [11/875] Compiling CNIODarwin shim.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [11/875] Compiling tls_record.cc
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [12/875] Compiling sha1-armv8.ios.aarch64.S
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [13/875] Compiling sha1-armv8.linux.aarch64.S
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [14/875] Compiling CBacktrace backtrace.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [15/875] Compiling CBacktrace dwarf.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [16/875] Compiling CBacktrace mmap.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [17/875] Compiling CBacktrace atomic.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [18/875] Compiling CAsyncHTTPClient CAsyncHTTPClient.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [18/875] Compiling CNIOBoringSSLShims shims.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:28] [18/875] Compiling CNIOHTTPParser c_nio_http_parser.c
[2022-07-28 21:24:33] remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimizationerror building image: error building stage: failed to execute command: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1
[2022-07-28 21:24:33] 
[2022-07-28 21:24:33] command exited with code 1
[2022-07-28 21:24:48]  ! Build failed (exit code 1)
```

Could you please explain what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The Swift compiler is running out of memory and helpfully crashing without any error message. You need to compile on something that provides more memory to the build machines, either by specking it higher or using GitHub actions to build it. This is a known issue with digital ocean and Swift